# Where do followers go when not at their home?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Recently, I noticed my follower Cicero disappeared on me. I went to the sanctuary, but he was not there, so I used the console command moveto to bring him to me. Interestingly, instead of following me, he walked out of the sanctuary and off into the wilderness. I followed him until he was attacked by a saber cat. After which he resumed normal follower activity. The question is, where was he going? Where do followers go when they aren't going home? I think it's a glitch, but they have to be going somewhere right? Is there  default location that NPCs go to?

Answer (score 2):

**Followers walk home.**

Followers don't simply disappear from your side and magically appear at home when they're dismissed; rather, they have to take the long way home -- that is, they have to walk.

Skyrim, of course, is a dangerous place. While walking, they can be attacked just like you. It sounds like your buddy Cicero here did exactly that. Followers are also quite persistent -- once a battle starts, pretty much the only way it ends is when one side or the other is dead (followers have no concept of "the better part of valor"); the death of that saber cat must have reset his battle AI, whether or not it's what he was fighting when you teleported him. (Do note, however, that NPCs other than those referenced by quests -- including invisible quests, so this includes followers -- simply won't spawn outside of a given distance from you, so once a follower gets a certain distance from you they aren't likely to run into anyone. Not unless you again come within "range" of them.)

Note that similar things can happen *without* dismissing your follower -- sometimes they get attacked by creatures you don't even notice while walking with you. They'll again fight to the death in that situation, and meanwhile you may not even know there's a fight going on at all! (This happens to me *all the gorram time!*) I don't think this is what happened in your case, though, because entering another worldspace (in this case the Sanctuary) will pull your (active, i.e. not-dismissed) follower out of an active combat and have them appear next to you again.

All of that said, sometimes the game just simply glitches. I've seen all kinds of bizarre behavior in Skyrim from glitches. If you hadn't dismissed Cicero (relatively) recently, then a glitch is probably the most likely explanation. Do note that if you're using the console anyway, you can almost always reset any character by using `disable` followed by `enable`.

Comment: Well, he wasn't going home because I was in the sanctuary (his "home") when I teleported him, and he walked out and started walking on the road out of the pale. I got curious and decided to follow him to see where he was going, but then he got attacked and started following me again.

Comment: @Crubleigh He could have been walking home and got into a fight; you teleported him, interrupting the fight, but he was still in "fight mode" and wandered off to go find his target. The battle with the saber cat "reset" his AI.

Comment: The safest thing to do is to return home and then dismiss them, they'll safely stay indoors. Serena is an exception, she's marked essential and so is invincible. She can deal with anything that comes her way.